# Android: getting website as string

Tags: java, android

I am currently in a curious situation: my goal is to get the `html` of a website and convert it into a `String` so that I can essentially read what is on the website. However, my code returns an error; I have isolated the line of code that contains the error, but I am unable to make it work. As shown in the error log below, the type of cast is incorrect. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

```
public class FirstDisplay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_display);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deliver);
        final TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headline);

        class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String response = "";
                for (String url : urls) {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    try {
                        HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                        InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(content));
                        String s = "";
                        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                            response += s;
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return response;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //textview1.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
            }
        }

        button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                AsyncTask<String, Void, String> headline = task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.google.com" });
                //HERE IS THE LINE OF CODE THAT CONTAINS THE ERROR
                textview1.setText((CharSequence) headline);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Here is the error log:

```
07-25 18:14:42.359: W/dalvikvm(9268): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416dfda0)
07-25 18:14:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 18:14:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): Process: com.app.myfirstapp, PID: 9268
07-25 18:14:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.myfirstapp.MainDisplay$1DownloadWebPageTask cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Comment: You need to use json to get dara

Comment: What happens if you comment that line out, then change the line in your `onPostExecute` to `textview1.setText(result);`?

Comment: @Takendarkk when I do that the `textView1` just gets changed to a blank bok

Comment: Alright. If you just print the String in your `onPostExecute()` e.g. print it to a log, does it display what you expect? I'm curious if the data you are getting back is what you expect.

Comment: @Takendarkk hmm when I do that I don't get anything, it seems that the String result has nothing in it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it, but yes it appears that the actual gathering of html from the website is where the problem lies. Perhaps you can research other methods of trying to grab the html of a website.

Comment: @user3866661 Try logging the `response` variable in `doInBackground()` or setting a breakpoint and debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
textview1.setText((CharSequence) headline);
```

Headline is an async task, not a string (or other charsequence).  Delete this line, and set the text in onPostExecute

Comment: I tried that, but when I do that, the textView is blank. Also, wouldn't I need to provide the URL somewhere in onPostExecute for that to happen?

Comment: " wouldn't I need to provide the URL somewhere in onPostExecute for that to happen" no, the URL should only be needed in `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is some really old code of mine, but I think it used to work:

```
static class scrapeIt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(get);
                String bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                return bodyHtml;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Internal-Error: #0237";
        }
    }
```

I believe your issue lies in trying to cast an AsyncTask to a "string" which is not allowed, what you want to do is get the string generated by the AsyncTask and work with that.